# Add new property to object if found in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects and each object has an id. I have another array with id values. If an objects id is found in arrayOfIds, I would like to add new property called **found** and set to true. I was thinking of using findIndex as a possible function to use here.

```
const arrayOfObjects = [ { id: '123' }, { id: '456' }, { id: '789' } ]
const arrayOfIds = ['456']
```

Expected Output

```
const arrayOfObjects = [ { id: '123' }, { id: '456', found: true }, { id: '789' } ]
```

Comment: What have you try so far?

Comment: Do any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```html
const arrayOfObjects = [ { id: '123' }, { id: '456' }, { id: '789' } ]
const arrayOfIds = ['456']

arrayOfObjects.map((object) => {
  if(arrayOfIds.includes(object.id)) {
    object.found = true;
  }
})

console.log(arrayOfObjects);
```

Comment: map function doesn't mutate the origin array. You should print the returned array.

Comment: No need, the object within the array is mutated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: As I said before, there is no need to return a new array, the array is just an array of object references. The object is updated and that's what matters. Run the code and look at the output.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make sense to convert your `arrayOfIds` to a Set to allow O(1) lookup.

```
const ids = new Set(arrayOfIds);
const augmentedObjects = arrayOfObjects.map(obj => {
  if (ids.has(obj.id)) {
    obj.found = true;
  }
  return obj;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Set` from the array and use `Array#map` along with `Set#has`.

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [ { id: '123' }, { id: '456' }, { id: '789' } ]
const ids = new Set(['456']);
const res = arrayOfObjects.map(o => ({...o, ...ids.has(o.id) && {found: true}}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map through the objects and spread the object with the `found` property.

```js
const output = arrayOfObjects.map((obj) => {
   if (arrayOfIds.includes(obj.id)) {
      return {  ...obj, found: true };
   }
   return obj;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by creating a lookup object. Create the lookup object from `arrayOfIds` and use that lookup object when traversing `arrayOfObjects` array and make certain changes.

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [{ id: '123' }, { id: '456' }, { id: '789' }];
const arrayOfIds = ['456'];
const lookup = Object.fromEntries(arrayOfIds.map((x) => [x, { found: true }]));
const ret = arrayOfObjects.map((x) => ({ ...x, ...lookup[x.id] }));
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run a `map` over the array of objects, and use the `includes` to add `show: true` by spreading the existing object else return the original object.
You could try something like this

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [{ id: "123" }, { id: "456" }, { id: "789" }];
const arrayOfIds = ["456"];
const result = arrayOfObjects.map((item) => {
  if (arrayOfIds.includes(item.id)) {
      return {
              ...item,
              found: true
      };
  }
  return item;
});
console.log(result);
```